Google OAuth return http redirect uri when in setting it's https
I have set up Google OAuth for my website.

With Publishing status, I set Testing and in credentials, the redirect URI is http://vya.daotao.ai/auth/complete/google-oauth2/, Sign in with Google action works correctly
With Publishing status, I set In Production, and in credentials the redirect URI is https://vya.daotao.ai/auth/complete/google-oauth2/, I got Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch, the redirect URI is in HTTP protocol while in Google setting it is HTTPS protocol



I deployed the system on AWS within ELB, ACM, and custom domain
Please help me resolve the trouble! Thank a lot

The redirect uri your app is sending is HTTP not HTTPS

You need to configure your app to run https in production and add the correct redirect uri to google cloud console.
Production apps must run HTTPS
You may also need to remove flowName=GeneralOauthFlow as this is not going to be a valid redirect uri.  Remember it is your code or the library which is probably configuring the redirect uri for the Oauth flow but i cant say that for sure as you have not posted your code.
